# what is the default value received for map of map when used value in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4, qmap

I have a `QMap<QString, QMultiMap<int, QString> > data;`

if I say `data.value(key);`  -> what will be the return value if value with that key is not present ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A default constructed `QMultiMap<int, QString>` i.e. an empty multimap.